# Tensorflow: Regarding tensorflow functions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow. I have the following problem:

input: list of floats (or a dynamic array. In python list is the datatype to be used)
Output: is a 2-d array of size `len(input)` × `len(input)`

## Example1:

Input:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Output:

```
[[0.09003057, 0.24472847, 0.66524096], 
 [0.26894142, 0.73105858, 0.0       ], 
 [1.0,        0.0,        0.0       ]]
```

I tried to create the function using `while` loop and calculating each row independently and concatenating them, but my instructor asked me to explore other ways.

Can you suggest me an idea on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code with the while loop?

Comment: What do you want to do with the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following approach:

1. Repeat the input array to create a square matrix tiled the input data
2. Create a mask with consists of ones in the left upper corner
3. Do softmax using the mask. Note that we cannot use `tf.nn.softmax` here because it will give small probabilities to those zeros also

Here is a TensorFlow (v0.12.1) code that does this:

```
def create_softmax(x):
    x_len = int(x.get_shape()[0])

    # create a tiled array
    # [1, 2, 3] 
    # =>
    # [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
    x_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(x, 0), [x_len, 1])

    # get the mask to do element-wise multiplication
    mask = tf.ones_like(x_tiled) # returns an array of the same size filled with 1
    mask = tf.matrix_band_part(mask, 0, -1) # zeros everythings except from the upper triangular part 
    mask = tf.reverse(mask, [False, True]) # reverses the y dimension

    # compute masked softmax
    exp = tf.exp(x_tiled) * mask
    sum_exp = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(exp, reduction_indices=1), (-1, 1))

    x_softmax = exp / sum_exp

    return x_softmax
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late for your class, but hopefully it will help someone.

If your goal is to simply output a `len(input)xlen(input)` array, you can matrix multiply a `1xlen(input)` tensor with your input array after expanding its dimensions to `len(input)x1`:

```
input_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [len(input)])
input_shape = input_.get_shape().as_list()
tfvar = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,input_shape[0]], mean=0.0,
                                    stddev=.01, dtype=tf.float32))

def function(input_):
    x = tf.expand_dims(input_, axis=1) # dims = len(input)x1
    return tf.matmul(x,tfvar) # mtrx multiplication produces 3x3 mtrx
```

This function should generalize to any 1D `input_` tensor and produce a square `len(input_)xlen(input_)` tensor.

If your goal is to train a tensorflow variable to produce the provided output exactly, you can then train `tfvar` with a loss function and optimizer:

```
desired_output = tf.constant([[0.09003057, 0.24472847, 0.66524096], 
                              [0.26894142, 0.73105858, 0.0       ], 
                              [1.0,        0.0,        0.0       ]],
                              dtype=tf.float32)

actual_output = function(input_)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(actual_output-desired_output))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    cost, opt = sess.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict={input_:input})
```

Note, if you want a more robust training session, add a bias, a non-linearity, and more layers.

Comment: too late, I graduated in july. :D